# Is there a way to get rid of the $ character in a TCurrencyEdit control?

Tags: delphi, controls, decimal, delphi-7

I'm working in Delphi 7 and trying to make an edit box where you can enter decimals.

There doesn't appear to be anything in the Delphi 7 base library for this other than TCurrencyEdit. However, it tacks on a `$` to the beginning of the value. Is there anyway to get rid of this "feature"?

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with Delphi, so this is a total stab: is there an edit mask property that you can manipulate to remove it?

Comment: As far I Know the `TCurrencyEdit` is a thirdparty component.

Comment: I'd take a stab and say that it's using CurrencyToStr which defaults to prepending the result with CurrencyStr Format setting in sys utils, you could try setting that to '' and see what happens

Comment: Ctrl-Click on `TCurrencyEdit`. Open the source code and look at it.   We have no idea what this is.   StackOverflow is not a place for people to guess what code you've got in your pocket.

Comment: Heh I thought it was part of the standard library. My mistake

Comment: TCurrencyEdit isn't in the "base library," and even if it were, this is still the wrong question to ask. If you want an edit control for editing numbers, then ask for *that*, and you might get a link to [Peter Below's tutorial on writing an edit control](http://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.vcl.components.writing/msg/41b62f85dd405cdf), which pretty much lays out the whole task.

Comment: Earlz; You thought so because you haven't learned to Ctrl-Click on things.  Curiosity is essential for a developer.

Answer (score 7):

(Can't you enter decimals in an ordinary `TEdit`?)

As far as I know, there is no `TCurrencyEdit` in the VCL that ships with (any version of) Delphi. Anyhow, for this, you could use the `TMaskEdit`. Perhaps the format `#999999999.99;1;_` will do. Still, I wouldn't praise this solution for its user-friendlyness!

The most user-friendly thing to do, I believe, is to use an ordinary `TEdit` with no restrictions. Then you can parse the text entered by the user when you need to. And then you can accept inputs like `1 000` as well as `1000` and `1000.00`. You can even respect the local decimal separator, and accept `1000,00` (in Sweden, for instance).

[But make sure that there is no ambiguity. The user might get upset if he enters `1000,000` and considers this to equal 1000 kronor and 000 öre, and then you take 1000000 kronor from his account!]

Comment: Use the `DecimalSeparator` and `ThousandSeparator` global variables for parsing, so you know what the user meant by `,`.

Comment: You can also catch user input as they're typing and deny certain characters from going in there in the first place - using the TEdit's key events. You can find details of doing this on Google.